# How to delete parent node when child node fire clicked event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to delete `<p>` node including it's all children when the `<span>` is clicked. The `<span>` is located inside the `<p>`.

The HTML example is:

`<p>Hello World!<span>x</span></p>`

I want to achieve this with JavaScript not jQuery.

My code is:

```
spancomment.addEventListener('click', deleteComment(this), false);
function deleteComment(e) {
    e.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.parentNode.parentNode);
}
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'e.parentNode.parentNode')

I followed: [How to remove the parent element using plain JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727717/how-to-remove-the-parent-element-using-plain-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to pass the function `reference` as a event handler,

```
spancomment.addEventListener('click', deleteComment, false);
function deleteComment(e) {
    this.parentNode.remove();
}
```

Also you can simply use `.remove()` over the parent node.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/7dwv7guh/)