# Delete div with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my View, I'm dynamically add divs like this via JS:

```
<div id="detail[0]">
        <input name="detail.Index" type="hidden" value="0" />
        <input name="detail[0].details_name" type="text" />
        <input name="detail[0].details_value" type="text" />
        <input class="btn" type="button" value="Delete" />
</div>
```

The question is how to delete the chosen one by clicking the Delete button in div?

JavaScript that adds new divs:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $('.plus').click(function()
    {
        ++i;
        var html2add = "<div id='detail[" + i + "]'>" +
            "<input name='detail.Index' type='hidden' value='" + i + "' />" +
            "<input name='detail[" + i + "].details_name' type='text' />" +
            "<input name='detail[" + i + "].details_value' type='text' />" +
            "<input class='btn' type='button' value='Delete' />"+
            "</div>";
        $('#details_part').append(html2add);
    })
})
```

Comment: `this.parentNode.remove()`?

Comment: do you want to delete with id detail[0]?

Comment: choose `div` with `$(this).closest('div')` and then `remove()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the parent element using plain javascript..!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727717/how-to-remove-the-parent-element-using-plain-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete the `div` containing the delete button, just use the `remove()` function:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function(){
  var cur = $(this);
  cur.parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A node cannot commit suicide (remove itself), therefore you must remove it from its parent node like this:

```
<script>    
function deleteItem (id) {
      var item = document.getElementById(id);

      item.parentNode.removeChild(item)
    }
</script>
<div>
  <div id="detail[0]">
          <input name="detail.Index" type="hidden" value="0" />
          <input name="detail[0].details_name" type="text" />
          <input name="detail[0].details_value" type="text" />
          <input class="btn" type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteItem('detail[0]')" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Codepen example: https://codepen.io/getreworked/pen/MmVMJB

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jquery you can do

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
     $(this).closest("div").remove();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.

This one will **hide** the div using purely JavaScript.

```
 <div id="detail[0]">
     <input name="detail.Index" type="hidden" value="0" />
     <input name="detail[0].details_name" type="text" />
     <input name="detail[0].details_value" type="text" />
     <input class="btn" type="button" onclick="removeDiv('detail[0]')" value="Delete" />
 </div>

<script>
 function removeDiv(id){
   document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
  }
 </script>
```

Just pass the parameter of the ID of your parent div.

This is Using jQuery:

```
 <div id="detail[0]">
     <input name="detail.Index" type="hidden" value="0" />
     <input name="detail[0].details_name" type="text" />
     <input name="detail[0].details_value" type="text" />
     <input class="btn" type="button" value="Delete" />
  </div>

 <script>
 $(function(){
     $('.btn').click(function(){
       $(this).parent().remove();
     });
 });
</script>
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

```
// Include below jquery 1.7 script in your file first    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js">

// then use this code to remove   
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function(){
         $('.btn').live('click' , function(){
           $(this).parent('div').remove();
         });
     });
</script>
```