# Getting Error when I am using parentElemnt or parentNode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some lists on my website and within every list, there are two buttons. one of them is a delete option. when I click on the delete option that specific element needs to be deleted. I have tried using `parentElement` `parentNode` but nothing was working.

I have also tried this solution [How to remove the parent element using plain Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727717/how-to-remove-the-parent-element-using-plain-javascript) but it was not working for me. Getting this error

```
 script.js:15 
 script.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentElement' of undefined
```

It'd be really very helpful If I can get some suggestions on this problem

```js
function remove(e) {
  e.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
}
```

```html
<ul class="todo" id="todo">
  <li id="todoList">
    <span id="todo-title"></span>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="remove" onclick="remove();" id="remove">
      <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 22 22" style="enable-background:new 0 0 22 22;" xml:space="preserve"><rect class="noFill" width="22" height="22"></rect><g><g><path class="fill" d="M16.1,3.6h-1.9V3.3c0-1.3-1-2.3-2.3-2.3h-1.7C8.9,1,7.8,2,7.8,3.3v0.2H5.9c-1.3,0-2.3,1-2.3,2.3v1.3c0,0.5,0.4,0.9,0.9,1v10.5c0,1.3,1,2.3,2.3,2.3h8.5c1.3,0,2.3-1,2.3-2.3V8.2c0.5-0.1,0.9-0.5,0.9-1V5.9C18.4,4.6,17.4,3.6,16.1,3.6z M9.1,3.3c0-0.6,0.5-1.1,1.1-1.1h1.7c0.6,0,1.1,0.5,1.1,1.1v0.2H9.1V3.3z M16.3,18.7c0,0.6-0.5,1.1-1.1,1.1H6.7c-0.6,0-1.1-0.5-1.1-1.1V8.2h10.6V18.7z M17.2,7H4.8V5.9c0-0.6,0.5-1.1,1.1-1.1h10.2c0.6,0,1.1,0.5,1.1,1.1V7z"></path></g><g><g><path class="fill" d="M11,18c-0.4,0-0.6-0.3-0.6-0.6v-6.8c0-0.4,0.3-0.6,0.6-0.6s0.6,0.3,0.6,0.6v6.8C11.6,17.7,11.4,18,11,18z"></path></g><g><path class="fill" d="M8,18c-0.4,0-0.6-0.3-0.6-0.6v-6.8c0-0.4,0.3-0.6,0.6-0.6c0.4,0,0.6,0.3,0.6,0.6v6.8C8.7,17.7,8.4,18,8,18z"></path></g><g><path class="fill" d="M14,18c-0.4,0-0.6-0.3-0.6-0.6v-6.8c0-0.4,0.3-0.6,0.6-0.6c0.4,0,0.6,0.3,0.6,0.6v6.8C14.6,17.7,14.3,18,14,18z"></path></g></g></g></svg>
    </button>

    <button class="complete" onclick="complete();">
      <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 22 22" style="enable-background:new 0 0 22 22;" xml:space="preserve"><rect y="0" class="noFill" width="22" height="22"></rect><g><path class="fill" d="M9.7,14.4L9.7,14.4c-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.2l-2.7-2.7c-0.3-0.3-0.3-0.8,0-1.1s0.8-0.3,1.1,0l2.1,2.1l4.8-4.8c0.3-0.3,0.8-0.3,1.1,0s0.3,0.8,0,1.1l-5.3,5.3C10.1,14.3,9.9,14.4,9.7,14.4z"></path></g></svg>
    </button>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `e` is the event object, it doesn't have `parentElement`. You need `e.target.parentElement`. Or actually in your code `e` is `undefined`. You've to pass the event object from an inline listener: `onclick="remove(event);"`.

Comment: Pass event parameter to function like this `onclick="remove(event);"` and access parent element as @Teemu said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pass the event to `remove()` like this `onclick="remove(event)` and use `e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.remove();` because [`e.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) will always refer to the button as opposed to [`e.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) which identifies the element on which the event occurred and which may be its descendant.

```js
function remove(e) {
  e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
}
```

```html
<ul class="todo" id="todo">
  <li id="todoList">
    <span id="todo-title"></span>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="remove" onclick="remove(event);" id="remove">
      <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 22 22" style="enable-background:new 0 0 22 22;" xml:space="preserve"><rect class="noFill" width="22" height="22"></rect><g><g><path class="fill" d="M16.1,3.6h-1.9V3.3c0-1.3-1-2.3-2.3-2.3h-1.7C8.9,1,7.8,2,7.8,3.3v0.2H5.9c-1.3,0-2.3,1-2.3,2.3v1.3c0,0.5,0.4,0.9,0.9,1v10.5c0,1.3,1,2.3,2.3,2.3h8.5c1.3,0,2.3-1,2.3-2.3V8.2c0.5-0.1,0.9-0.5,0.9-1V5.9C18.4,4.6,17.4,3.6,16.1,3.6z M9.1,3.3c0-0.6,0.5-1.1,1.1-1.1h1.7c0.6,0,1.1,0.5,1.1,1.1v0.2H9.1V3.3z M16.3,18.7c0,0.6-0.5,1.1-1.1,1.1H6.7c-0.6,0-1.1-0.5-1.1-1.1V8.2h10.6V18.7z M17.2,7H4.8V5.9c0-0.6,0.5-1.1,1.1-1.1h10.2c0.6,0,1.1,0.5,1.1,1.1V7z"></path></g><g><g><path class="fill" d="M11,18c-0.4,0-0.6-0.3-0.6-0.6v-6.8c0-0.4,0.3-0.6,0.6-0.6s0.6,0.3,0.6,0.6v6.8C11.6,17.7,11.4,18,11,18z"></path></g><g><path class="fill" d="M8,18c-0.4,0-0.6-0.3-0.6-0.6v-6.8c0-0.4,0.3-0.6,0.6-0.6c0.4,0,0.6,0.3,0.6,0.6v6.8C8.7,17.7,8.4,18,8,18z"></path></g><g><path class="fill" d="M14,18c-0.4,0-0.6-0.3-0.6-0.6v-6.8c0-0.4,0.3-0.6,0.6-0.6c0.4,0,0.6,0.3,0.6,0.6v6.8C14.6,17.7,14.3,18,14,18z"></path></g></g></g></svg>
      remove
    </button>

    <button class="complete" onclick="complete();">
      <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 22 22" style="enable-background:new 0 0 22 22;" xml:space="preserve"><rect y="0" class="noFill" width="22" height="22"></rect><g><path class="fill" d="M9.7,14.4L9.7,14.4c-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.2l-2.7-2.7c-0.3-0.3-0.3-0.8,0-1.1s0.8-0.3,1.1,0l2.1,2.1l4.8-4.8c0.3-0.3,0.8-0.3,1.1,0s0.3,0.8,0,1.1l-5.3,5.3C10.1,14.3,9.9,14.4,9.7,14.4z"></path></g></svg>
    </button>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks but still having error sying Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentTarget' of undefined. Can you please check

Comment: the snippet works correctly, are you sure you have passed the event to `onclick` attribute of the button `<button class="remove" onclick="remove(event);" ...`?