# How do I remove a specific tags from HTML using JS?

Tags: javascript

```
<figure>
<p>Hello please remove parent figure tag. I just want the this child p tag.</p>

</figure>
```

Comment: <figure><p>keep p tag only remove figure tag using js.</p></figure>

Comment: Sometimes this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727717/how-to-remove-the-parent-element-using-plain-javascript

Answer (score 1):

This is the plain Javascript solution for your problem:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <figure id='x'><p id='y'>Hello</p></figure>

 <script type='text/javascript'>
   let a = document.getElementById('x').innerHTML;

   document.getElementById('x').remove();

   document.write(a);

  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```