# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'destroy')

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

How is this fixed in the code? https://jsfiddle.net/a6dp1soy/

To reproduce error, click on the X Button

First click on the play svg, then the X button.

```
  const resetVideos = document.querySelectorAll(".exit");
  resetVideos.forEach(function resetVideoHandler(video) {
    video.addEventListener("click", function resetVideoHandler() {
      video.parentElement.player.destroy();
      console.log("hit")
    });
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be just replacing

```
video.parentElement.player.destroy();
```

with

```
video.parentElement.parentElement.removeChild(video.parentElement);
```

I took reference from here [How to remove the parent element using plain Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727717/how-to-remove-the-parent-element-using-plain-javascript) and `video.parentElement` object

And then next part shall be creating that element again on clicking play

Comment: After clicking on the same play svg a 2nd time, the screen is empty. Code Does Not Work https://jsfiddle.net/fqombdxu/

Answer (score 0):

You should find the element with class `wrap` where your player is stored on creation.

```
  const resetVideos = document.querySelectorAll(".exit");
  resetVideos.forEach(function resetVideoHandler(video) {
    video.addEventListener("click", function resetVideoHandler() {
      var player = this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('wrap')[0].player;
      player.destroy();
      console.log("hit")
    });
  });
```

JS fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/c54b0faw/